# new javascript Date from a string and formatting template?

Tags: javascript

I have an application that works in several "cultures".  I will be using many date formats.

I have a string with my format (i.e. 'd/m/y', but keep in mind this is variable) and 2 text inputs with dates in that given format.

I need to compare the dates in input box 1 to input box 2.  I had a method that did this fine, until we added the international formatting.

```
new Date(endDate) >= new Date(startDate)
```

This used to work with U.S. only dates.  It does not now.  Is there a method I can use that works like this?:

```
new Date(endDate, 'd/m/y')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider [moment.js library](http://momentjs.com/), which may relieve you from many date manipulation problems, since Javascript can't parse locale formats.  For your case, you'd write

```
moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

which would create a "moment" object, parsing date string to the provided template.

Comment: Thanks! This library is awesome, does everything I need it to do.